# How can I use Python to refactor nested function calls into lines of code?

Tags: python, automated-refactoring

I'm looking for some way to do this with Python itself, not using an IDE.

Example:

```
def upper(string):
    return string.upper()

def reverse_string(string):
    return string[::-1]

string = 'abc'
reverse_upper = reverse_string(upper(string))
```

Converts to:

```
string = 'abc'
reverse_upper = string.upper()[::-1]
```

I'm considering making a solution that works recursively with [inspect.getsourcelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsourcelines). Is there any other function or library that will get me further along?

Comment: This is called [inline expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) or "inlining". Why do you want to do it in Python?

Comment: @kaya3 It's a portion of a code rewriting program, not something I want to do on one codebase. I knew the "inline" term, but not "inline expansion". I think that's going to get me in the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60286269/how-can-i-use-python-to-refactor-nested-function-calls-into-lines-of-code#comment106638804_60286269) from @kaya3 got me here.

There are two repos that do this that I can use as starting points: [inliner](https://github.com/orf/inliner) and [atinline](https://github.com/rfk/atinline). Neither are maintained, but I can use them for reference.